# Click and drag in windows 7 sticks after holding left click for a couple of seconds.

Tags: mouse, touchpad, mouse-click

If I click and drag my mouse anywhere (such as to highlight text, or drag a file), if I continue to hold left click for about 2 seconds, the mouse will act like I'm still dragging after I release the button. So, if I highlight some text and take too long to do it, I can release the click and move the mouse around and the highlighted section will respond according, or whatever file I'm trying to drag will keep moving, until I click again. This happens with my touchpad, my graphics tablet, and any scroll wheel USB mouse I connect.

I searched through my mouse settings but couldn't find anything related to this. Am I missing something? Is there anything I can do to make this stop happening? Because it is consistently the same amount of time before the stick happens, and it's happening on multiple different kinds of devices, I'd assume it's not a hardware issue.

Comment: This sounds like some accessibility feature to me. Have you tried looking through your Accessibility Settings for anything related to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds an awful lot like you have **ClickLock** turned on:

[image: 1]

Comment: My computer seems to be entering ClickLock by itself. That is without it being checked.