# Why does clicking my mouse select mutliple lines of text?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, touchpad, dell-vostro

I am experiencing a weird issue on my dell laptop.  When I click a webpage is will automatically select a few lines of text after my cursor.  This happens whether I am using the buttons below the touchpad, or using the touchpad itself (via tapping).

I've recorded a gif of this happening here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UViv.jpg

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it do the same with a regular mouse?

Comment: Are you using a Synaptics Mouse driver?

Comment: Do you have [ClickLock](http://superuser.com/a/918517/138343) turned on?

Comment: Is the problem limited to specific browser? What browser is it? Or is the problem global? What system then?

Comment: I tried to disable all the special dell settings, but it went away when I plugged in a mouse. Before I only noticed it in Chrome, but now with a mouse plugged in, the touchpad is working normally.  I'll see if I can narrow this down some more, but for now I'll just use a mouse.