# Any Ideas Why My Razer Naga LMB Interrupting Itself When Held Down?

Tags: usb, drivers, mouse, razer-mouse

Recently, my Naga EC NASA has been interrupting itself and "letting go" of the LMB if you hold it down for more than a second or two, only to immediately re-engage the button. I've gotten a replacement from Razer twice already, but the problem persists.

## Things I've tried

1. Wireless, and Wired Mode
2. Multiple USB ports
3. Different USB cables
4. Different Wireless Charging Ports
5. Getting Replacements from Razer
6. Deleting, and Reinstalling Naga Specific Drivers
7. Deleting and Reinstalling all Razer Programs
8. Deleting and Reinstalling all Razer Drivers
9. Creating New Profiles in Razer Synapse as instructed by Razer support
10. Swapping LMB and RMB in config, the problem just persists in the new layout as RMB stopping.
11. Tried a different non-razer mouse.
12. Tried it in a different computer, seemed even worse on another computer.

Comment: Did the replacement immediately exhibit the problem or has this been happening over the course of some months?

Comment: The problem was immediate, just got the replacement today started happening right away.

Comment: Well that (hopefully) rules out a defective or worn out microswitch. Do you have any softwares that might be capturing or modifying mouse behaviour such as AutoIt, Autohotkey or similar? It is completely consistent behaviour, as in it absolutely always does this, or is it intermittent and only does it sometimes?

Comment: Can you go to your Control Panel, then Mouse and see if Clicklock is enabled? If so, disable it. https://superuser.com/a/918517/19943

Comment: It seems to do it randomly. Sometimes immediately, other times after about 3 or 4 seconds. I don't have anything like AutoIt, or Autohotkey. I also can't think of anything that would modify mouse behavior installed.

Comment: I had the same issue recently with a different mouse. It was corrected by replacing it. Looks like you will have to replace again.

Comment: Clicklock was not enabled, oddly enough I just tried it with clicklock on, to see if things would change and it seems to still have the problem with it on as well, will just randomly let go of things or stop dragging. Which makes me think it's not a mechanical problem.

Comment: Yeah. It's an odd one. The random timing and general nature of the problem suggests mechanical fault, but the fact you say you tried another unrelated mouse suggests that it's software. Can you try this mouse on another computer to completely rule it out?

Comment: Yeah that was my fear AEonAX, I just hope they'll cover another replacement as this has been 2 mice in a row from them with the same problem. Was hoping to troubleshoot the problem away but it's not looking like it will be possible.

Comment: Mokubai, I actually just went and did it on my room mates computer, same issue, seemed even more frequent on their computer. Which also confuses me even more.

Comment: Just seen your edit, if it is the same (or worse) on another computer then it seems very likely to be the mouse hardware.

Comment: Yep, gonna contact razer again, see if they have any more suggestions, and if those don't work try to get another replacement. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you have found the solution to your problem, please add it as an answer and accept it so the question appears as a solved question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, kind of new took me a moment to figure out how to do that. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lowering the Polling rate on the mouse form it's default of 1000hz, in the program provided by Razer eliminated the problem entirely.